# one-to-one relationship but of multiple types in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm creating an online shop with Django. I figured since there could be different types of item for sale that share some attributes and fields, I'd better make an Item Model and other models subclass it.
So I now have an abstract Item model and some other models like Dress, Pants and shoes.
Now I wanna have a new model (e.g. Comment) which should have a relationship with the Item model.
But since Item model is abstract I can't do it.
Is there way I could have a one to one relationship whose one side could accept different types?
Some thing like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    item = models.ForeignKey(to=[Dress, Pants, Shoes])
```

Answer (score 1):

One `Foreing key` field can lead only to one `instance`, in a database it would look like this:

```
|id|  item |
|13|t-shirt|
```

The best way to solve your problem is to use these three models:

```
class Item_type(models.Model):
    #here you should create as many instances as you have types of your items
    # one item_type = Dress, second = Pants, third = Shoes
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Item(models.Model):
    #here you create your item, with title for example Nike Brand new shooes
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    #and choosing type in oneToOneField = shooes
    item_type = models.OneToOneField(Item_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Comment(models.Model):
    #here you have your comments for your Item
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Wouldn't GenericRelation be better? I'm not saying your answer is bad, just curious

Comment: @TrueGopnik if you can show example, we can compare

Comment: Okay, could you look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Generic Relations sounds like solution, in your Comment model add these fields:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    [Other fields]
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

and in your abstract Item model add GenericRelation field

```
class Item(models.Model):
    [Other fields]
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

Comment: i think my solution is easier for this task, but in case OP is forced to this database structure your answer would solve a problem

Comment: Thanks. And how can I do the same but for Many To Many relationship? In Order model the is an items field in which all the items to be bought should be stored.

Comment: You could create Model which store Order and GenericRelation to items, and on item you could add same fields like on Comment